# RegEx for range and increment check

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any RegEx which can test this scenario.

1. String with comma separated number where left number should be less than right. 
   Correct example: 1,2,3   4,10,20
   Incorrect example: 3,2,1  4,1,20
2. String can have - separator like 1-25, where left should be smaller than right and the string should not have number between this range.

Correct example: 1-50,51,52,55-60  1,2,3-10,12,20
Incorrect example: 1-50,49,20,60     2,3,1-10,11

Should I write separate function for this?

Thanks

Comment: You *could* write a regex for that but it's going to be virtually unmaintainable.

Comment: The idea of a regex is not to validate logic inside expressions, but only expressions itself. This means that the part "left should be smaller than right" is not a correct use case for a regex. In my opinion, you should validate the regex first (the part that states that it is a comma separated list of numbers, with the posibility of ranges), and then, in a second iteration, validate the logic inside your string.

Comment: it's as @jfc says for example filter for each number and add it to a list or something like it and then go through it and look if the next number is bigger than the one before

Comment: You can't do that with Regular Expressions. Simply not possible without utilising a programming language (JS here).

Comment: @revo I disagree slightly - you *could* do that with regex. Here is a sample `/1-[2-9]|2-[3-9]|3-[4-9]|4-[5-9]|5-[6-9]|6-[7-9]|7-[89]|8-9/` - that validates if you have only two single-digit numbers on either side of a `-` sign and the left one is smaller than the right one. The complexity of creating a regex for anything more than two single-digit numbers explodes, so it's *extremely hard* to do it by hand. So, *technically* the task is possible. It still shouldn't be attempted in any serious application. And I apologise for causing any headaches and/or vomit with that regex.

Comment: @VLAZ Your given example fulfills the smallest part of the requirement and for this reason you may not generalize it to the whole one. You are saying `that validates...` but I don't see it doing any validation. The problem with such questions is that (for the second requirement specifically), one should find all `\d+-\d+` patterns in a given input string then check if it is semantically correct and traverse whole comma-separated list and look for each number to not be in the captured ranges which is simply not possible with Regular Expressions alone.

Comment: @revo i was thinking the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a non-regex solution. You could [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the numbers at `,` and then [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) them based on their numerical value. Use the *Max* value if the value is a range. Then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the sorted array. Check if the resulting string is same as the original string

```js
const getMaxValue = str => str.includes("-") ? +str.split("-")[1] : +str;

const checkInOrder = str => str === str.split(",")
                                  .sort((a,b) => getMaxValue(a) - getMaxValue(b))
                                  .join(",")

console.log(checkInOrder("1,2,3,4,10,20"))
console.log(checkInOrder("3,2,1,4,1,20"))
console.log(checkInOrder("1-50,51,52,55-60"))
console.log(checkInOrder("1,2,3-10,12,20"))
console.log(checkInOrder("1,2,3-10,12,20"))
console.log(checkInOrder("1-50,49,20,60,2,3,1-10,11"))
```

Comment: It seems like legit. Will run it with other test cases. Thanks BTW

Comment: above function did not pass 1,3,1-12 this test. As it's failing to check if 1 already exists or not in the string. But i learn new way to write function with this syntax. Thanks for that

Comment: @PraveenRawat The examples you have given in the question don't have overlapping numbers. The implementation uses the max value for comparing when a range is given. `getMaxValue` function can be changed depending on how you want to handle ranges. Whether you want to use min value or max value. How should `1,3,1-12` be sorted? The current implementation keeps them in that same order because `12` is bigger than `1` and `3`

Comment: exactly its not sorted and function should fail to do so. But you are right I need to modify it as per my need. Accepting this as answer and will update mine when its done.

Comment: @PraveenRawat So, what is the correct order for `1,3,1-12`?

Comment: idea is user can enter numbers in comma separated or range. What is in comma separated string should not be in range and number can not exists if it is already in range or comma separated part.

Comment: @PraveenRawat aah, so this is an invalid input itself. So, you don't want to have a number within another range mentioned. You can save the array returned by `sort` in a variable. Loop through it and whenever a range is encountered check if the previous number (max value, if it's also a range) and the next number (min value, if a range) are within the min and max value of the current range in context. `break` from the loop if faulty value is found. After this check, you can do the `join` the sorted array and compare with original string check

Comment: yes that is what i am doing right now. thanks for quick help BTW.

Comment: I will be checking range and add numbers in that range to a temp string and while doing that I will check current number in range should not exists in temp string. That way it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex for this task would be really difficult. I think a better approach is to do it using JavaScript:

```js
const isValid = arr => {
  const items = [];
  const ranges = [];
  const inRange = (range, x) => x >= range.start && x <= range.end;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    const x = +arr[i];
    const rangeParts = /(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)/.exec(arr[i]);
    if (rangeParts) {
      const range = { start: +rangeParts[1], end: +rangeParts[2] };
 
      const validRange = range.start < range.end &&
        ranges.every(r => range.start > r.end || range.end < r.start);
      if (!validRange) return false;
      
      const itemsInRange = items.some(item => inRange(range, item));
      if (itemsInRange) return false;
      
      ranges.push(range);
    }
    const inRanges = ranges.some(r => inRange(r, x));
    if (inRanges) return false;

    if (i > 0 && items[items.length-1] >= x) return false;
    
    items.push(x);
  }
  return true;
};

console.log(isValid(['1', '2', '3', '4']));
console.log(isValid(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5-7']));
console.log(isValid(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5-7', '1-3']));
console.log(isValid(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5-7', '7-8']));
console.log(isValid(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5-7', '8-10']));
console.log(isValid(['1', '20', '3', '4', '5-7', '8-10']));
```

Comment: thanks man for helping. Will run the same with other test cases.